# (Done) Why was the question about monitoring an employees private network closed?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request, legal-questions

[Can my employer legally monitor my personal network activity when I'm working from home?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/179703/can-my-employer-legally-monitor-my-personal-network-activity-when-im-working-fr)

The question was closed as

> Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department. Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors. Questions seeking legal advice should be directed to legal professionals.

I don't see anything about company policy in there and yes, the question asks whether something is legal. But I think we had an agreement that only complex cases that need a lawyer should be closed as "needs a lawyer", while the questions where knowledgable non-lawyers (for example HR reps or where I live anybody with a professional education, because education on labor law is part of it) can answer should remain open.

Of the close voters, is anyone from the EU and has *doubts* whether that is illegal?

Because to me it seems pretty obvious. There is no complex case here. Any HR rep should be able to tell that the behaviour as suspected would be highly illegal.

Comment: Pretty clearly answerable with no need to delve deeply into lawyerese so I reopened it.